# What is the process for getting a deleted answer re-reviewed after it's been improved?

Tags: discussion

I had my post answer deleted on

[Docker - a way to give access to a host USB or serial device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-a-way-to-give-access-to-a-host-usb-or-serial-device/53892718#53892718)

My understanding is that Stackoverflow has no way for me to contact or ping the people who deleted my post to ask for re-review after I've improved it.
What should I do now?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: it was considered as spam because you were integrating the same personnal link to all your answers